# Verilog error while declaring a array

Tags: arrays, compiler-errors, syntax-error, verilog, xilinx

```
reg [11:0] rom_sin_type [0:4095]= '{12'h000, 12'h003, 12'h006, 12'h009, 12'h00d, 12'h010, 12'h013, 12'h016, .....};
```

In verilog,when i am synthesizing the above line of code which contains 4096 values, each of 12 bit, its showing error as below given.

**expecting ';', found '='**

**expecting 'endmodule', found '{'**

Please can anyone help me , how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please show some more code along with pointing out line of error.

Comment: Im storing 4096 values, it will be huge code to show up here

Comment: Are you using verilog or system-verilog? What happens if you do something like: `reg [11:0] rom_sin_type [0:4095]; initial begin rom_sin_type = '{12'h000, 12'h003, 12'h006, 12'h009,...} end` Your `endmodule` Might be at wrong place.

Comment: Im using Verilog code, basically im coding NCO where in "rom_sin_type  and rom_cos_type " im stroing values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verilog does not support the `'{}` syntax. It is a SystemVerilog ([IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html)) feature; refer to § 5.10 *Structure literals*, § 5.11 *Array literals*, § 7.2.2 *Assigning to structures*, § and 10.9 *Assignment patterns*.

You can either enable SystemVerilog (all modern Verilog simulators are SystemVerilog simulators) or assign the the Verilog way:

```
reg [11:0] rom_sin_type [0:4095];
initial begin
  rom_sin_type[0] = 12'h000;
  rom_sin_type[1] = 12'h003;
  rom_sin_type[2] = 12'h006;
  rom_sin_type[3] = 12'h009;
  .....
end
```

Comment: my xilinx version is 14.2,  it is not synthesizing , do you have any idea , how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You can try  **for** loop also.

```
genvar  i;
for (i=0;i<4096;i= i+1) begin
    assign a[i] = i;
end
```

I am not sure whether the rom_sin_type will require an assign statement or not.

Comment: where to declare the values?

Comment: ` reg [11:0] rom_sin_type [0:4095];
  initial begin
   genvar  i;
   for (i=0;i<4096;i= i+1) begin
     assign rom_sin_type[i] = i;
 end`

Comment: i have to do it for 4096  values , for both sin and cos LUT update and assign them?  :(

Comment: I am not sure if I got your last comment right. The **FOR** loop should be able to assign 4096 in those 3 lines. Also, you can assign sin and cos LUT in same **FOR** loop.

Comment: I understood, but i have to assign 4096  values to

Comment: I understood, but i have to assign 4096  values to `rom_sin_type[i] ` , like below   rom_sin_type[0] = 12'h000;
  rom_sin_type[1] = 12'h003;
  rom_sin_type[2] = 12'h006;
  rom_sin_type[3] = 12'h009; ......     rom_sin_type[4096] = 12'h000;

Comment: 12bits will lead to 4096 unique. In your example, the values will be repeated.  You can add some conditions to have your desired values.

`genvar  i;
for (i=0;i<4096;i= i+3) begin
    assign a[i] = i;
end`